# Order by a column by fixing an exact value at the top in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

```
Column A    Column B
--------------------
    1          3
    2          3
    3          3 
    3          3
    4          3
```

When I order by column A like `ORDER BY A ASC`, it returns an output of `1 2 3 3 4` or `ORDER BY A DESC` returns an output of `4 3 3 2 1`.

But I need to fix one or two value at first position. Which I need to compare with column B. So which value I matched with column B it will be at 1st position.

Like `ORDER BY A ASC` will return an output like `3 3 1 2 4`. Is it possible?

Comment: Please include sample data which makes your question clear.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`ANSI-SQL`](http://www.whoishostingthis.com/resources/ansi-sql-standards/) syntax it should read like this:

```
SELECT a, b 
FROM tablename
ORDER BY CASE WHEN a=b THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, a, b
```

Answer (score 0):

This is easy, since you can order by multiple criteria. Order by equality first and then all the rest.

```
select a, b 
from tablename
order by if(a=b, 0, 1), a, b
```

Comment: `order by CASE WHEN a=b THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ASC, a, b`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen this is no join at all, just one single table with a `order by` clause. Should be just a few percent slower because of a=b test.

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal what is the bebefit of `CASE WHEN` here? I find it more complicated. To be honest I would use `order by a=b, a, b`. ;-)

Comment: It is not valid SQL-92 syntax, read the info about `sql` tag.

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal is right, he didn't specify his RDBMS , hence you couldn't guarantee this works. `CASE EXPRESSION` would work on any RDBMS, therefore it is the correct solution.

Comment: Ah, so `if...` does not work on any database. Does `order by a=b` evaluate `a=b` to 0 / 1 in every database? It is a bit ugly to read and a bit C-style, I have to confess.

Comment: Nope, will work on MySQL , other RDBMS has different syntax for `IF`

Answer (score 0):

You might just want to order by the difference:

```
order by abs(a - b)
```

Comment: Can you explain ? I want to keep the matched value on the top. Not the difference.

Comment: @parvessuzon . . . This orders by the absolute value of the difference of the two columns.  That appears to be how you are choosing the rows with "3" in columns `a` and `b`.